# UFT cannot recognize Windows Frame on Web Browser

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, hp-uft

I am trying to automize our tests. We have a browser version of SAP Event Manager. 
[image]
I was trying to capture the events from login, click on the Event Manager link, then enter a tracking number in Event Handler List. The actions I got from capturing are like below:
[image]

When I try to run these scripts, I got the following error:
[image]

I am new to UFT. The parent object "Frame("itsframe1_20190917181918.39975")" looks like something to do with the date and time, maybe that's why it cannot find when execute it. But I do not know how to change it to make UFT recognize it during execution. I tried Object Spy and add it to Object Repository, but still the Frame is in this form. Does anyone have any idea of what to?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have UFT's SAP addin installed and enabled?

SAP web applications create frames and other objects whose description doesn't work well with plain Web support but the SAP addin knows how to ignore the dynamic attributes (as well as adding a lot of functionality).

Comment: No, I don't have SAP addin. Is it free? And I can download it to install upon my existing UFT installation?

Comment: @Lucy all UFT addins are included in UFT's price, if you re-run the installation and choose **modify** (IIRC) you will see the option to add additional addins.